# Timezone date field Email Template - OpenERP7

Tags: xml, timezone, odoo

I have a little problem with an email template, I include within body_html datetime field, at the time of sending the mail that arrives with the wrong date (over 5 hours) I guess that is the issue of time zones; I have no idea how I can specify in the mail template that should take the user's time zone, I have seen that to address this in the reports with "Aeroo reports" is enclosed in formatLang field `(<formatLang (o.f_start, date_time = True)>)` but for the case of the mail template does not work.

What I can think of at the moment is to create a functional field that returns me the date converted to the time zone of the user but do not think is the most correct way to solve this problem.

I thank you so much any help on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

try this
[[ formatLang(o.f_start, date_time = True) ]] hope this will help you

Vote For This